# Developing android application on Android device or online including APK generation

Tags: android, ide, apk

I wish to develop Android app on my Android device. I need IDE (Android / Web), that gives me:

- Editing the source code.
- Compiling the code (errors etc.).
- Create APK installation.

If there is just graphic-designer, *but it allows me to download the source code* - it's the best.

Comment: http://www.android-ide.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,the IDE named [AIDE](http://www.android-ide.com/) from you can edit , compile and run your app on your device

more info visit http://www.android-ide.com